# How to append current date to AM/PM time from a column and display it in a format YYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.000 as time in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I need to convert a value in SQL Server in format:

```
CONVERT (SMALLDATETIME, CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), s.ExceptionDate, 121) + ' ' + StartTime)
```

where StartTime is a column in a table with populated values to Postgresql.
Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: I don't understand if you are using Postgres or SQL Server and for which product you need a solution

Comment: I am trying to convert a value in SQL server to postgresql

Comment: So you need a T-SQL solution because the code runs in SQL Server? Then how does Postgres come into play? Are you using a linked server or a foreign table?

Comment: No, let me clarift the snippet that I have pasted is a part of MS SQL existing code. I am migrating it to Postgresql and am looking for a Postgres equivalent code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what that code does, but assuming that `exceptiondate` is of type `date` and `starttime` is of type `time` you can do:

```
to_char(exceptiondate + starttime, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');
```

[Adding](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) a `time` to `date` yields a `timestamp` which then can be [formatted using `to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)